# OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"r-base\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

Tags: python, r, docker, rna-seq

I have previously created a docker container using similar code as below, but I ran a basic python script to print "Hello". I am trying to perform RNASeq in R and keep running into issues when I try to run my code.

Here's what is in my Dockerfile.

```
FROM debian:stretch-slim

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends r-base r-base-dev git python3 \
    && apt-get clean

COPY file.R /
```

On my terminal, I ran:
`docker build -t username/python_git_r_hello .`

This ran successfully, but when I followed up with:
`docker run -it username/python_git_r_hello:latest r-base file.R`

I got the following error: docker:

```
Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"r-base\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

Please help, I am new to using docker.

Answer (score 0):

The executable is named `R`, not `r-base`.  Run:

```
docker run -it username/python_git_r_hello:latest R file.R
```